# SwiftUI Menu Dropdown Appearance

Tags: swiftui, menu, dropdown

I'm currently learning swift, swiftui and other components and I am stuck with the appearance of the buttons in the menu.
I have an add Button at the top bar which appears as a sheet. When the menu button is pressed, the buttons from this menu are appearing at the top. I left space below and my question is, can I change the appearance of the buttons from the top to the bottom?

This is the ui of the app:

[image: Image of the ui]

My Code looks like this ->

This is the view which appears as sheet:

```swift
struct EinkaufAddView: View {
    
    @State var artikelTextField: String = ""
    @State var anzahlTextField: String = ""
    @State var kategorieNamen: String = "Kategorie"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        Section("Produkt") {
                            TextField("Hinzufügen...", text: $artikelTextField)
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3).cornerRadius(10))
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    VStack {
                        Section("Anzahl") {
                            TextField("0", text: $anzahlTextField)
                                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                                .frame(height: 50)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3).cornerRadius(10))
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                
                Section("Kategorie") {
                    Menu(kategorieNamen) {
                        Button("Obst") {
                            kategorieNamen = "Obst"
                        }
                        Button("Milchprodukte") {
                            kategorieNamen = "Obst"
                        }
                        Button("Fleisch") {
                            kategorieNamen = "Obst"
                        }
                        Button("Getränke") {
                            kategorieNamen = "Obst"
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3).cornerRadius(10))
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 30)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Produkt hinzufügen")
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .bold()
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.blue.cornerRadius(25))
            })
            .padding()
            
            .navigationTitle("Artikel hinzufügen")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    EinkaufAddView()
}
```

This is the view with the .sheet appearance:

```swift
struct Einkaufsliste: View {
    
    @State var showSheet: Bool = false
    @StateObject var vm = EinkaufViewModel()
    let kategorien: [Kategorie] = [
        Kategorie(title: "Obst", titleColor: Color.yellow, anzahl: 5),
        Kategorie(title: "Fleisch", titleColor: Color.purple, anzahl: 2),
        Kategorie(title: "Milchprodukte", titleColor: Color.blue, anzahl: 10),
        Kategorie(title: "Getränke", titleColor: Color.green, anzahl: 8)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(kategorien) { item in
                            NavigationLink {
                                EinkaufslisteDetailView(vm: vm, kategorieName: item.title)
                            } label: {
                                EinkaufsListView(kategorieNamen: item.title, anzahlKategorien: item.anzahl)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.plain)
                            .foregroundStyle(item.titleColor)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing: Button(action: { showSheet.toggle() }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                    EinkaufAddView()
                        .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.8)])
                }
            )
            .navigationTitle("Einkaufsliste ")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    Einkaufsliste()
}

struct EinkaufsListView: View {
    
    let kategorieNamen: String
    let anzahlKategorien: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .stroke()
            
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text(kategorieNamen)
                
                Spacer()
                
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    Text("\(anzahlKategorien)")
                }
                
                Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .font(.title2)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .frame(width: 350, height: 60)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5).cornerRadius(15))
        .padding(.top)
    }
}
```

Please ignore the rest of the code, it is a total mess .

I have looked at the internet but couldn't find anything useful.
I think I heard somewhere that this cannot be changed, but I am still asking maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Maybe try a different view type, eg. `Picker`.

Comment: I think the position of the popup depends on where the menu appears on the screen and the only way to control it is to move the launch item higher up the screen. For your code, if you try moving the `Section` with the menu to the top of the `VStack` that contains it (in other words, above the `HStack`) then you will find that it drops down below the section (at least, it does on an iPhone 15), so the threshold level is probably around half the screeen height. However, you can at least fix the order of items in the menu by using `.menuOrder(.fixed)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I started with Swift UI back then, I was also happy about every idea, hence my suggestion,

I would create an array from the options (makes the code a bit easier and is super easy to maintain)

```
let kategorien = ["Obst", "Milchprodukte", "Fleisch", "Getränke"]
```

And you need a state variable that contains the current state:

```
@State private var ausgewaehlt = "Obst"
```

Here the Picker:

```
   Section("Kategorie") {
                    Picker("Kategorie", selection: $ausgewaehlt) {
                        ForEach(kategorien, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                    .frame(height: 150)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1).cornerRadius(10))
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                            
                }
```

The picker uses the variable selected for the currently selected option and lists all categories. As the picker uses binding, the changes after each change in saved to the state variable.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, that was very useful! I will definitely use that thanks ☺️